# Initial value problem with substitution

Tags: integration, derivatives, substitution, initial-value-problems

I'm having a lot of difficulty with a and b of this problem. I tried using Bernoulli but for some reason it isn't working, I may be doing something wrong.

[image: problem]

Thank you.

Comment: the equation is homogeneous.

Comment: How would I proceed to answer the question? @Matematleta